# Controlling browser forward/back functions in web application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm writing a web-based application for internal use within the business where I work. It's a fairly complex application, with a lot of forms that will allow the user to view and enter data, which once saved will be stored in a database.

One thing I'm anxious to avoid is allowing a situation to exist where a user might enter large amounts of data in the browser, and then (either deliberately or inadvertently) navigate off the page without saving the changes. To this end, I have already implemented an entry page which opens up a new browser window in which there are no navigation controls at all; only what is provided on the web pages themselves.

However, there are two potential ways in which a user could still lose data:

1. The browser Close button is still enabled, and a user could potentially lose work by clicking it inadvertently. I can probably live with this, as it falls at the extreme end of helping the user not to shoot himself in the foot.
2. In Internet Explorer (and, apparently, in Firefox) the Backspace button works like a Back button. I only discovered this accidentally, and have as yet been unable to find a simple way of stopping this behaviour. This is potentially a problem, as an inadvertent use of the Delete key (e.g. having positioned the cursor in a read-only textbox, or when the cursor isn't on any particular field in the page) will navigate off the page.

What I would like to do, as a minimum, is prevent Backspace from navigating off a page if that page has any user-writable fields on it and any of those fields have been changed by the user since the form was loaded. Ideally, I would like to disable this particular use of the Backspace key completely, while the user is logged into this web application. The two possible ways that I can think of, for achieving this, are: (1) clear the browser's history as each page is loaded, or (2) trap the Backspace key and only allow it to work if the cursor is positioned within a field whose text can be changed (e.g. a textbox).

Can anyone suggest how I could achieve either of these things? The solution needs to be programmatic, rather than something that has to be manually configured on every browser in the company.

Comment: In case anyone else has a need to solve this problem, I found a solution on another website, here: http://mspeight.blogspot.com/2007/05/how-to-disable-backspace-in-ie-and.html. Judging by the number of positive reactions there, this "functionality that your users have learned to expect in their daily activities at work and at home" is nothing of the sort, and is something of a nuisance to many people.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of blocking* functionality that your users have learned to expect in their daily activities at work and at home, why not work *with* it? Make the "back" button actually take them to the previous screen as expected, and use AJAX to silently save the form as they fill it out (say, every 5 or 10 seconds), so when they return to the form you can check to see if they already have partial, unsubmitted values saved and reload them.

This approach aligns with the realities of web-based applications *and* delights users if implemented well. An alert that says "you did something wrong" just frustrates users and makes them trust your application less. Remember - users almost never do the wrong thing. It's our applications that aren't aligned with usage.

<sup>* more like *trying* to block functionality. As you've discovered, people who designed the interwebs and web browsers never really intended for site developers to totally disable moving back and forward in the navigation history.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? You can ask them if they are sure before they leave.

```
var changes = false;        
window.onbeforeunload =
        function()
        {
            if (changes)
            {
                var message = "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?\n\nYou still have unsaved changes.\n\nPress OK to continue or Cancel to stay on the current page.";
                if (confirm(message)) return true;
                else return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the onbeforeunload event handler fire every time a postback was done? I don't want prompts popping up on every occasion that they do anything that navigates off the current page; only if they use the Backspace key in a context where it will try to navigate off the page. Too many such prompts would result in users (a) getting sick of them, and (b) getting used to clicking 'OK' automatically.

Comment: Yes. Set the changes value to false before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Javascript's `window.unload` event.

This is fired when the use tries to leave the page. You can't totally stop them leaving the page, but you can give them a chance to cancel.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
window.onbeforeunload() {
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```